# Karabiner Elements: How to bind "right_command + e" to open Emacs?

Tags: keyboard, emacs, karabiner

I've been trying to use Karabiner Elements to bind the "right_command + e" combination to open Emacs on my macOS. Here's the configuration snippet I originally used to bind the "left_command + e" combination:

```json
{
    "description": "left_command + e -> Emacs",
    "manipulators": [
      {
        "from": {
          "key_code": "e",
          "modifiers": {
            "mandatory": [
              "left_command"
            ]
          }
        },
        "to": [
          {
            "shell_command": "open -a emacs"
          }
        ],
        "type": "basic"
      }
    ]
}
```

I attempted to modify the configuration based on a suggestion to simply change "left_command" to "right_command", like so:

```json
{
    "description": "right_command + e -> Emacs",
    "manipulators": [
      {
        "from": {
          "key_code": "e",
          "modifiers": {
            "mandatory": [
              "right_command"
            ]
          }
        },
        "to": [
          {
            "shell_command": "open -a emacs"
          }
        ],
        "type": "basic"
      }
    ]
}
```

However, this modification didn't work as expected. Emacs is not being launched when I press `right command` and `e`.

This is my [whole config file](https://github.com/pdelfino/my-karabiner-elements-config/blob/main/karabiner.json) for Karabiner elements. Also, I am using an American keyboard with Brazilian Portuguese input - if it matters. As a fellow user requested, this is my keyboard, [a keychron k2.](https://www.keychron.com/products/keychron-k2-wireless-mechanical-keyboard) Note that I swapped the keys on the hardware to match my karabiner config.

[image]

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Could you provide guidance on how to bind "right_command + e" to open Emacs using Karabiner Elements?

Comment: Define "didn't work" for the studio audience.

Comment: I just updated, @MarcWilson. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: There was a time when the left and right Cmd keys both returned the event code for the left key.  My AEK and AEKII are both like this (yes, they're very old).  What keyboard are you making this change for?  Karabiner Elements used to have a tool that would show what keys were being pressed, does it still?

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @MarcWilson. I just updated my question.